# GroupMe Bot made entirely in PHP

Tags: php, chat

I made a GroupMe bot entirely in PHP and would like a review on the code and would also like suggestion on what I should add.  Here is the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/desultory/GroupMe-Bot/tree/d4ba4ee5b35d4c7e86ab0f81b72e09f1e94d7d76).

I have a few directed questions in addition to wanting a general code review:

Is my method of storing settings a good idea, I don't want to use sql because I want this to be very portable.

Is my panel very safe?  I don't have very much verification on it and it is supposed to be hosted in a webdir that has something like apache authentication or the like.

I made some pretty heavy changes to my code and made the panel also autogenerate config files if they are not present.  It works really well with some testing but I don't know how bad the practices are since it's a whole load of php and html mixed and would really appreciate feedback on it.

I'll also post all of the parts here:

bot.php:

```
<?php
//Includes all functions and parses the post data into appropriate variables
include 'functions.php';
include 'lights.php';
$callback = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$attachments = $callback->attachments;
$avatar = $callback->avatar_url;
$name = $callback->name;
$type = $callback->sender_type;
$text = $callback->text;
$userid = $callback->user_id;
$admins = read_array('admins.php');
$ignored = read_array('ignore.php');
$settings = read_array('settings.php');
//If logging is enables in the config, this logs the chat to specified file and directory
logging($userid, $name, $text);
//Only handles messages from users to prevent infinite loops
if ($type == 'user' && !in_array($userid, $ignored) && $text[0] != '/') {
    //Basic response is a simple response to a found phrase
    basic_response($text, $name, $userid);
    //If the Weather Underground API token and location are set and weather has been enabled, this will return a forecast if someone says "weather"
    if ($settings['weather']) {
        weather_response($text);
    }
    //If anyone says "bitcoin" and the bitcoin setting is enabled, this will return the price in USD
    if ($settings['bitcoin']) {
        btc_response($text);
    }
    //If anyone says "ethereum" and the ethereum setting is enabled, this will return the price in USD and BTC
    if ($settings['ethereum']) {
        eth_response($text);
    }
    //If anyone says "litecoin" and the litecoin setting is enabled, this will return the price in USD and BTC
    if ($settings['litecoin']) {
        ltc_response($text);
    }
    if ($settings['lights']) {
        blink($ip, $pins, "50", "20");
    }
}
if (in_array($userid, $admins) && $type == 'user' && $text[0] == '/') {
    $command = parse_cmd($text);
    if ($text == '/help') {
        disp_help();
    } elseif ($text == '/ignorelist') {
        list_ignored();
    } elseif (strpos($text, '/ignore') !== FALSE && isset($command[0])) {
        send(add_ignore($command[0]));
    } elseif (strpos($text, '/unignore') !== FALSE && isset($command[0])) {
        send(del_ignore($command[0]));
    } elseif ($text == '/responses') {
        list_responses();
    } elseif (strpos($text, '/addresponse') !== FALSE && isset($command[0]) && isset($command[1])) {
        send(add_response($command[0], $command[1]));
    } elseif (strpos($text, '/delresponse') !== FALSE && isset($command[0])) {
        send(del_response($command[0]));
    } elseif ($text == '/admins') {
        list_admins();
    } elseif (strpos($text, '/getuserid') !== FALSE && isset($command[0])) {
        send("$command[0]'s User ID is " . get_user_id($command[0]));
    } elseif (strpos($text, '/addadmin') !== FALSE && isset($command[0])) {
        send(add_admin($command[0]));
    } elseif (strpos($text, '/deladmin') !== FALSE && isset($command[0])) {
        send(del_admin($command[0]));
    } elseif (strpos($text, '/enable') !== FALSE && isset($command[0])) {
        send(enable_custom($command[0]));
    } elseif (strpos($text, '/disable') !== FALSE && isset($command[0])) {
        send(disable_custom($command[0]));
    } elseif ($text == '/status') {
        list_status();
    } elseif ($text == '/lightson') {
        lights_on($ip, $pins);
    } elseif ($text == '/lightsoff') {
        lights_off($ip, $pins);
    } else {
        send('Invalid Command');
    }
}
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
function logging($userid, $name, $text) {
    include 'config.php';
    if ($log) {
        if (!is_dir($logdir)) {
            mkdir($logdir, $logdirchmod);
        }
        file_put_contents($logdir . '/' . $logfile, "$userid($name): $text\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
function basic_response($text, $name, $userid) {
    $responses = read_array('responses.php');
    foreach ($responses as $element) {
        if (stripos($text, $element[0]) !== FALSE) {
            $message = $element[1];
            $message = str_replace('%u', $userid, $message);
            if (stripos($message, '%n') !== FALSE) {
                $message = str_replace('%n', $name, $message);
                mention($message, $name);
            } else {
                send($message);
            }
        }
    }
}
function weather_response($text) {
    include 'config.php';
    if (stripos($text, 'weather') !== FALSE) {
        if (isset($wutoken) && isset($wuloc)) {
            $rawweather = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.wunderground.com/api/$wutoken/conditions/q/$wuloc.json"));
            $temperature = $rawweather->current_observation->feelslike_string;
            $weather = $rawweather->current_observation->weather;
            $icon = $rawweather->current_observation->icon_url;
            $forecast = "The weather is $weather with a temperature of $temperature";
            send_img($forecast, $icon);
        } else {
            send('WUnderground token and location are not set');
        }
    }
}
function btc_response($text) {
    if (stripos($text, 'bitcoin') !== FALSE) {
        $pricedata = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD"));
        $usdprice = $pricedata->USD;
        $message = "Bitcoin is worth \$$usdprice";
  $btclogo = 'https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/32x32/bitcoin.png';
  send_img($message, $btclogo);
 }
}
function eth_response($text) {
 if (stripos($text, 'ethereum') !== FALSE) {
  $pricedata = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD"));
  $usdprice = $pricedata->USD;
  $btcprice = $pricedata->BTC;
  $message = "Ethereum is worth \$$usdprice and $btcprice Bitcoin";
  $ethlogo = 'https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/32x32/ethereum.png';
  send_img($message, $ethlogo);
 }
}
function ltc_response($text) {
 if (stripos($text, 'litecoin') !== FALSE) {
  $pricedata = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=LTC&tsyms=BTC,USD"));
  $usdprice = $pricedata->USD;
  $btcprice = $pricedata->BTC;
  $message = "Litecoin is worth \$$usdprice and $btcprice Bitcoin";
        $ltclogo = 'https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/32x32/litecoin.png';
        send_img($message, $ltclogo);
    }
}
function curl_post($postfields) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
function send($message) {
    include 'config.php';
    $postdata = [
        'bot_id' => $bottoken,
        'text' => $message
    ];
    curl_post(http_build_query($postdata));
}
function send_img($message, $image) {
    include 'config.php';
    $attachments = [
        'type' => 'image',
        'url' => $image
    ];
    $postdata = [
        'bot_id' => $bottoken,
        'text' => $message,
        'attachments' => [$attachments]
    ];
    curl_post(json_encode($postdata));
}
function mention($message, $name) {
    include 'config.php';
    $loci = [
        stripos($message, $name),
        strlen($name)
    ];
    $attachments = [
        'loci' => [$loci],
        'type' => 'mentions',
        'user_ids' => [get_user_id($name)]
    ];
    $postdata = [
        'bot_id' => $bottoken,
        'text' => $message,
        'attachments' => [$attachments]
    ];
    curl_post(json_encode($postdata));
}
function store_array($array, $file) {
    $array = json_encode($array);
    file_put_contents($file, "<?php\n" . $array);
}
function read_array($file) {
    $array = file_get_contents($file);
    $array = str_replace('<?php', null, $array);
    $array = json_decode($array, true);
    return $array;
}
function get_bot_group() {
    include 'config.php';
    $bots = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots?token=$apitoken"));
    foreach($bots->response as $element) {
        if ($element->bot_id == $bottoken) {
            return $element->group_id;
        }
    }
}
function get_user_id($name) {
    include 'config.php';
    $user_id = 'No member with that name found';
    $groupid = get_bot_group();
    $groups = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups?token=$apitoken"));
    foreach($groups->response as $element) {
        if ($element->id == $groupid) {
            foreach($element->members as $member) {
                if (stripos($member->nickname, $name) !== FALSE) {
                    $user_id = $member->user_id;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $user_id;
}
function get_name($userid) {
    include 'config.php';
    $name = 'Invalid userid';
    $groupid = get_bot_group();
    $groups = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups?token=$apitoken"));
    foreach($groups->response as $element) {
        if ($element->id == $groupid) {
            foreach($element->members as $member) {
                if ($userid == $member->user_id) {
                    $name = $member->nickname;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $name;
}
function parse_cmd($command) {
    $command = explode(' -"', $command);
    array_splice($command, 0, 1);
    foreach($command as &$element) {
        $element = substr($element, 0, strlen($element) -1);
    }
    return $command;
}
function disp_help() {
    $help = <<<'EOHELP'
        '/help' displays this message
        '/ignorelist' lists all users who are being ignored
        '/ignore -"userid"' ignores all messages from specified user
        '/unignore -"userid"' removed ignore on specified user
        '/responses' displays all current responses
        '/addresponse -"find" -"respond"' adds a response to the "find" phrase %n = name, %u = userid
        '/delresponse -"find"' deletes a response for phrase "find"
        '/admins' displays all current admins
        '/getuserid -"name"' displays user id of a member of the group
        '/addadmin -"userid" adds the specified user ID to the admin list
        '/deladmin -"userid" adds the specified user ID to the admin list
        '/enable -"(weather|btc|eth)"' enables a custom response
        '/disable -"(weather|btc|eth)"' disables a custom response
        '/status' lists all settings and their current status
EOHELP;
    send($help);
}
function list_ignored() {
    $message = null;
    $ignored = read_array('ignore.php');
    foreach($ignored as $element) {
        $name = get_name($element);
        $message .= "$element($name)\n";
    }
    send($message);
}
function add_ignore($userid) {
    $ignored = read_array('ignore.php');
    $message = "Something bad happened :(";
    $name = get_name($userid);
    if (!in_array($userid, $ignored)) {
        if ($name !== 'Invalid userid') {
            $ignored[count($ignored)] = $userid;
            store_array($ignored, 'ignore.php');
            $message = "$userid($name) has been added to the ignore list";
        } else {
            $message = "No member associated with User ID \"$userid\" is in the group";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "$userid($name) is already being ignored";
    }
    return $message;
}
function del_ignore($userid) {
    $ignored = read_array('ignore.php');
    $message = "Something bad happened :(";
    $name = get_name($userid);
    if (in_array($userid, $ignored)) {
        array_splice($ignored, array_search($userid, $ignored), 1);
        $message = "$userid($name) was removed from the ignore list";
        store_array($ignored, 'ignore.php');
    } else {
        $message = "$userid($name) is not being ignored";
    }
    return $message;
}
function list_responses() {
    $message = null;
    $responses = read_array('responses.php');
    foreach($responses as $element) {
        $message .= "$element[0] -> $element[1]\n";
    }
    send($message);
}
function search_responses($needle) {
    $responses = read_array('responses.php');
    $counter = 0;
    $position = false;
    foreach($responses as $element) {
        if (stripos($element[0], $needle) !== FALSE || stripos($needle, $element[0]) !== FALSE) {
            $position = $counter;
        }
    $counter++;
    }
    return $position;
}
function add_response($find, $response) {
    $responses = read_array('responses.php');
    $message = "Something bad happened :(";
    if (search_responses($find) !== FALSE) {
        $message = "There is already a similar response for $find";
    } else {
        $responses[count($responses)] = [$find, $response];
        store_array($responses, 'responses.php');
        $message = "Added response $find -> $response";
    }
    return $message;
}
function del_response($find) {
    $responses = read_array('responses.php');
    $message = "Something bad happened :(";
    if (search_responses($find) !== FALSE) {
        array_splice($responses, search_responses($find), 1);
        store_array($responses, 'responses.php');
        $message = "Deleted response for $find";
    } else {
        $message = "There is not a response for $find, nothing to delete";
    }
    return $message;
}
function list_admins() {
    $message = null;
    $admins = read_array('admins.php');
    foreach($admins as $element) {
        $name = get_name($element);
        $message .= "$element($name)\n";
    }
    send($message);
}
function add_admin($userid) {
    $admins = read_array('admins.php');
    $message = "Something bad happened :(";
    $name = get_name($userid);
    if (!in_array($userid, $admins)) {
        if ($name !== 'Invalid userid') {
            $admins[count($admins)] = $userid;
            store_array($admins, 'admins.php');
            $message = "$userid($name) has been added to the admin list";
        } else {
            $message = "No member associated with User ID \"$userid\" is in the group";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "$userid($name) is already an admin";
    }
    return $message;
}
function del_admin($userid) {
    $admins = read_array('admins.php');
    $message = "Something bad happened :(";
    $name = get_name($userid);
    if (in_array($userid, $admins)) {
        array_splice($admins, array_search($userid, $admins), 1);
        $message = "$userid($name) was removed from the admin list";
        store_array($admins, 'admins.php');
    } else {
        $message = "$userid($name) is not an admin";
    }
    return $message;
}
function enable_custom($setting) {
    $settings = read_array('settings.php');
    $message = "Something bad happened :(";
    if ($settings[$setting] == 1) {
        $message = "Already enabled, no changes made";
    } else {
        $settings[$setting] = 1;
        $message = "Response enabled";
        store_array($settings, 'settings.php');
    }
    return $message;
}
function disable_custom($setting) {
    $settings = read_array('settings.php');
    $message = "Something bad happened :(";
    if ($settings[$setting] == 0) {
        $message = "Already disabled, no changes made";
    } else {
        $settings[$setting] = 0;
        $message = "Response disabled";
        store_array($settings, 'settings.php');
    }
    return $message;
}
function list_status() {
    $message = null;
    $settings = read_array('settings.php');
    foreach($settings as $setting => $state) {
        $message .= "$setting -> $state\n";
    }
    send($message);
}
```

lights.php:

```
<?php
//set this to the pins you have you relays on
$pins = [
    0,
    1,
    3,
    4
];
//set this to the ip where you have the gpio.php utility (https://github.com/desultory/PiScripts/blob/master/gpio.php)
$ip = '';
function perform_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
    return(trim(curl_exec($ch)));
    curl_close($ch);
}
function multicurl($ips) {
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach ($ips as $element=>$ip) {
        $ch[$element] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch[$element], CURLOPT_URL, $ip);
        curl_setopt($ch[$element], CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch[$element], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch[$element], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$element]);
    }
    $active = null;
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
        if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
            do {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
    }
    foreach ($ips as $element=>$ip) {
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$element]);
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh);
}
function get_gpio_state($ip, $pin) {
    $request = "http://" . "$ip" . "/gpio.php?" . "p=" . "$pin" . "&r=1";
    return perform_curl($request);
}
function blink($ip, $pins, $delay, $count) {
    usleep($delay);
    foreach($pins as $element=>$pin) {
        $pinstate[$element] = get_gpio_state($ip, $pin);
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        foreach($pins as $element=>$pin) {
            if ($pinstate[$element]) {
                $requests[$element] = "http://" . "$ip" . "/gpio.php?" . "p=". "$pin" . "&w=1" . "&s=0";
                $pinstate[$element] = 0;
            } else {
                $requests[$element] = "http://" . "$ip" . "/gpio.php?" . "p=". "$pin" . "&w=1" . "&s=1";
                $pinstate[$element] = 1;
            }
        }
        multicurl($requests);
    }
    usleep($delay);
}
function lights_on($ip, $pins) {
    foreach($pins as $element=>$pin) {
        $requests[$element] = "http://" . "$ip" . "/gpio.php?" . "p=". "$pin" . "&w=1" . "&s=1";
    }
    multicurl($requests);
}
function lights_off($ip, $pins) {
    foreach($pins as $element=>$pin) {
        $requests[$element] = "http://" . "$ip" . "/gpio.php?" . "p=". "$pin" . "&w=1" . "&s=0";
    }
    multicurl($requests);
}
```

panel.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
if (file_exists('config.php')) {
    include 'functions.php';
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $delete = $_POST['delete'];
        $responses = read_array('responses.php');
        foreach ($delete as $element) {
            $responses[$element] = null;
        }
        $responses = array_values(array_filter($responses));
        store_array($responses, 'responses.php');
    }
    if (isset($_POST['find']) && isset($_POST['respond']) && !empty($_POST['find']) && !empty($_POST['respond'])) {
        $responses = read_array('responses.php');
        $responses[count($responses)] = [$_POST['find'], $_POST['respond']];
        store_array($responses, 'responses.php');
    }
    if (isset($_POST['setting'])) {
        $settings = read_array('settings.php');
        $update = $_POST['setting'];
        foreach ($settings as $key=>$value) {
            if (isset($update[$key])) {
                $settings[$key] = 1;
            } else {
                $settings[$key] = 0;
            }
        }
        store_array($settings, 'settings.php');
    }
    if (isset($_POST['del_setting'])) {
        $settings = read_array('settings.php');
        $delete = $_POST['del_setting'];
        foreach ($settings as $key=>$value)  {
            if (isset($delete[$key])) {
                unset($settings[$key]);
            }
        }
        store_array($settings, 'settings.php');
    }
    if (isset($_POST['new_setting']) && !empty($_POST['new_setting'])) {
        $settings = read_array('settings.php');
        $settings[$_POST['new_setting']] = 1;
        store_array($settings, 'settings.php');
    }
    if (isset($_POST['send']) && !empty($_POST['send'])) {
        send($_POST['send']);
    }?>
<title>PHP GroupMe Bot</title>
<style>
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
When adding a response, %n can be used to mention a user by name and %u will be replace by their user id
<form name="add" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="find" placeholder="Text to find">
    <input type="text" name="respond" placeholder="Text to respond with">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
<form name="delete" method="post" action="">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Find</th>
        <th>Respond</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $responses = read_array('responses.php');
    $iteration = 0;
    foreach ($responses as $element) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>$element[0]</th>";
        echo "<th>$element[1]</th>";
        echo "<th><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"delete[]\" value=\"$iteration\">";
        echo "</tr>";
        $iteration++;
    }?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Remove">
</form>
<form name="settings" method="post" action="">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $settings = read_array('settings.php');
    foreach ($settings as $key=>$value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>$key</th>";
        if ($value) {
            echo "<th><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"setting[$key]\" value=\"1\" checked>";
        } else {
            echo "<th><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"setting[$key]\" value=\"1\">";
        }
        echo "<th><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"del_setting[$key]\" value=\"1\">";
        echo "</tr>";
    }?>
    <tr>
        <th>Add setting</th>
        <th><input type="text" name="new_setting" placeholder="Name for new setting"></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <input type="submit" value="update">
        <input type="hidden" name="setting[]" value="1">
    </form>
    <form name="send" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="send" placeholder="Message to send">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form><?php
} else if (is_writeable('./')) {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $error = 0;
        if (!empty($_POST['apitoken']) && !empty($_POST['bottoken'])) {
            $apitoken = $_POST['apitoken'];
            $bottoken = $_POST['bottoken'];
            $config = "<?php\n\$apitoken = '$apitoken';\n\$bottoken = '$bottoken';\n";
            if (!empty($_POST['wutoken'])) {
                if (!empty($_POST['wuloc'])) {
                    $wutoken = $_POST['wutoken'];
                    $wuloc = $_POST['wuloc'];
                    $config .= "\$wutoken = '$wutoken';\n\$wuloc = '$wuloc';\n";
                } else {
                    $error = 1;
                    echo "You must specify a WeatherUnderground Location if you specify a token";
                }
            }
            $config .= "\$log = '1';\n";
   if (!empty($_POST['logdir'])) {
    $config .= "\$logdir = " . $_POST['logdir'] . ";\n";
   } else {
    $config .= "\$logdir = 'logs';\n";
   }
   if (!empty($_POST['logname'])) {
    $config .= "\$logfile = " . $_POST['logname'] . ";\n";
   } else {
    $config .= "\$logfile = 'log';\n";
   }
   if (!empty($_POST['logchmod'])) {
    $config .= "\$logdirchmod = " . $_POST['logchmod'] . ";\n";
   } else {
    $config .= "\$logdirchmod = '0755';";
            }
        } else {
            $error = 1;
            echo "You must specify an api token and bot token";
        }
        if (!$error) {
            $me = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.groupme.com/v3/users/me?token=$apitoken"));
            $id = $me->response->id;
            $admins = "<?php\n[\"$id\"]";
            if (!file_exists('admins.php')) {
                file_put_contents('admins.php', $admins);
            }
            if (!file_exists('ignore.php')) {
                file_put_contents('ignore.php', "<?php\n[]");
            }
            if (!file_exists('responses.php')) {
                file_put_contents('responses.php', "<?php\n[[\"test\",\"It works!\"]]");
            }
            if (!file_exists('settings.php')) {
                if (isset($wutoken) && isset($wuloc)) {
                    file_put_contents('settings.php', "<?php\n{\"weather\":1,\"bitcoin\":1,\"ethereum\":1,\"litecoin\":1,\"lights\":0}");
                } else {
                    file_put_contents('settings.php', "<?php\n{\"weather\":0,\"bitcoin\":1,\"ethereum\":1,\"litecoin\":1,\"lights\":0}");
                }
            }
            file_put_contents('config.php', $config);
            sleep(1);
            header("Refresh:0");
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP GroupMe Bot Setup</title>
</head>
<form name="setup" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" style="width: 50%;" name="apitoken" placeholder="Your GroupMe API token"><br>
    <input type="text" style="width: 50%;" name="bottoken" placeholder="Your GroupMe bot token"><br>
    <input type="text" style="width: 50%;" name="wutoken" placeholder="Your WeatherUnderground API token"><br>
    <input type="text" style="width: 50%;" name="wuloc" placeholder="Your WeatherUnderground Location Code"><br>
    <input type="text" style="width: 50%;" name="logdir" placeholder="Log directory, logs is the default"><br>
    <input type="text" style="width: 50%;" name="logname" placeholder="Log name, log is the default"><br>
    <input type="text" style="width: 50%;" name="logchmod" placeholder="Log chmod, 0755 is the default"><br>
<input type="submit" value="generate"><br><?php
} else {
    echo "Working directory is not writeable, either chown it to the webserver user and group or allow write permissions to everyone";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll only address specifically on the way you store settings.

Storing settings in a JSON file is a fine idea. I'd say there's a few things you do that aren't necessary.

You store the JSON in a PHP file, but start the PHP file with `<?php` and strip that out with `read_array()`. You don't need to start a PHP file with `<?php` if you're not actually gonna run it as a PHP file, but just want it to not be publicly accessible.

And on that same note, you can just use a `.json` file and either use the web server to prohibit web access to that file, or even better place that file outside the web root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Return early instead of having huge nested if blocks.

On panel.php you have this code,

```
if (file_exists('config.php')) {
   //massive amount of code
}
else{
  //show warning
}
```

Instead you can simplify by doing,

```
if (!file_exists('config.php')) {
   //show warning
   exit 1;
}
```

I also don't like the include statements inside of the  functions

```
function logging($userid, $name, $text) {
    include 'config.php';
    if ($log) {
        if (!is_dir($logdir)) {
            mkdir($logdir, $logdirchmod);
        }
        file_put_contents($logdir . '/' . $logfile, "$userid($name): $text\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

I think you would be better off passing those variables into the function rather than including the config file.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've almost entirely rewritten the bot and have posted the new code here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188513/php-based-groupme-bot-with-sqlite-and-control-panel if you want to look over the revised code.